# Clean install Pepper OS to Pepper Robot (not android version)?

Tags: pepper

Is there any way to install basic, english pepper os 2.5 to pepper robot? (1.6b)

As far as I know, the root privilege is not given to user, but since the ROS integration is possible as below, clean install is also possible (at least theoretically), right?

https://github.com/awesomebytes/pepper_os

Anybody know how to 'clean install' Pepper OS (Not android version tablet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in contact with robot lab recently and they gave me an opn file, I can share it with you or you can contact them yourself to get the file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Aleks4920 How can I contact you?

Comment: my apologies, I didn't see your message. If you would still like to get in contact please email me at alekz4920@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You can [factory reset](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/pepper-documentation/pepper-user-guide/settings/configuring-managing-pepper) in the settings of the robot.

To flash the system with a precise image, you can also use Choregraphe to do it, see [Can not complete Pepper robot factory reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235754/can-not-complete-pepper-robot-factory-reset). However I have no website to recommend to download a system image.

Comment: Thanks. I already know that. What I want is re-install the OS from image. is it possible?

Comment: I've just updated the answer to take this into account.